# C - String array, allocate or not '\0'?

Tags: c, arrays, size

For example we have  a string array, size of `i`

We take that string as input and to discover its size, we put into a `while` , when sees `EOF or '\0'` , loops ends.

Now it is allocation time. The size is `i`, so it means we do `stringarray[i]='\0'` .

While allocating, allocate in the size of `i or i+1 or i-1?` Because i tried all of them and they worked.

The last line, `'\0'` should be allocated?

Comment: If you don't want UB when treating the allocated memory as a 'string', then yes.

Comment: What do you mean by "string array"? Normally, that would be `char * []`. What you have appears to be an array of `char`. If the size is `i`, you cannot dereference `[i]`, but only `[i-1]`

Answer (score 3):

There are some points you are wrong about

1. `EOF` is not used as a string delimiter or end of string marker, only `'\0'` is used.
2. When you allocate `size` or `size - 1` bytes for a string of `size` characters, and then you copy the contents to the allocated block you will be accessing memory that your program is not authorized to acces thus causing *Undefined Behavior*, if it "*works*" it's just a coincidence. But the truth is that it's not **really** working. Undefined behavior is undefined, and sometimes something bad will happen while some other times you wont even notice it.

   You **must** allocate space for `size + 1` bytes.
3. Yes the space to to hold `'\0'` should indeed be allocated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should always allocate for the string-ending character. And yes, `my_string[i] = '\0'` should be true, if `i = strlen(my_string)`.

You say that you tried for `i`, `i + 1`, `i - 1`, and it worked, but the correct answer would be `i + 1`.

A string containing `"Hello\0"` has a length (calculated by `strlen()` in this case) of 5. *But* the true length is actually 6, since `strlen` doesn't count the ending character `'\0'`, so your `malloc` call should be `malloc( strlen(my_string) + 1);`

**A bit more about that:**

Why would it not crash then, if you allocate `i` or `i - 1`?

To answer that, I suggest you read more about how `malloc` works internally; [this link is pretty interesting](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/look-at-how-malloc-works-on-mac.html)

Basically, when you call `malloc` with a certain number of bytes, it will always allocate exactly that amount of bytes, *or more*, if the size you've asked for is not a multiple of some "quantum size". A simple example, taken from that link : if you allocate 3, 5, or 10 bytes, if the quantum size is 16, you'll get an allocation of 16.

Of course, that's just a simple way of explaining it, and `malloc` works differently depending on your OS.

Comment: Interesting what you say, but the actual reason why it might work is because it's undefined behavior. Your explanation is a good one, because if it's undefined behavior it doesn't necessarily means that there is no explanation for the observed behavior, and in this case, this might very well be what is happening.

Comment: Of course, it is undefined behavior. Asking `n` bytes of memory from malloc should give you `n` , not more. Writing more bytes on that chunk of memory, for example, may very well erase some metadata the system allocator stored, and you'd end up crashing at some later call to malloc, for no apparent reason :) . I figured we might as well explain a bit why it didn't crash, instead of just calling UB.

Comment: The memory beyond the last memory byte allocated for `my_string` is a *VALID* memory location. I think it's the primary reason for seeing no crash.

Comment: @EugeniuRosca Not necessarily, undefined behavior means undefined, anything can happen.

Answer (score 0):

> For example we have a string array, size of `i`

If you are referring *size* as `strlen`, then `stringarray[i] == '\0'` will probably be true.

> While allocating, allocate in the size of i or i+1 or i-1? Because i tried all of them and they worked.

Allocating another string as the same size of the first one? If so, allocate `i` bytes.

> The last line, '\0' should be allocated?

`i` bytes includes the space for the `'\0'`.

Comment: If we have an array of `i` members, doesn't that mean that the last valid index is `i-1`? So, wouldn't `stringarray[i]` point to a memory location outside of the (statically/dynamically) allocated space?

Comment: @EugeniuRosca `stringarray[i]` would be the NUL-terminator(`'\0'`) where `i` is `strlen(stringarray)`.